# Graphical representation of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, math-software

Which software (preferably: free/open source) can one use to graphically represent a complex function? I know that real functions can be easily represented with Octave or R; what can you recommend for complex functions?

Thanks in advance,
Lucian

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RiemannZeta%28x%2Biy%29)

Comment: The article "Phase Plots of Complex Functions" in the [June 2011 _AMS Notices_](http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/index.html) may have some relevant information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free software / online tool to plot complex functions as maps of grids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399467/free-software-online-tool-to-plot-complex-functions-as-maps-of-grids)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What free tools can I use to plot complex functions on the complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191604/what-free-tools-can-i-use-to-plot-complex-functions-on-the-complex-plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sage at http://www.sagemath.org/

*Edit by Rahul:* SAGE has a [complex_plot function](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/complex_plot.html) which visualizes complex functions using [domain colouring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring). An example can be seen in [this blog post about SAGE 3.4.1](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1124).

Comment: @Rahul : Thanks for the edit! (As a general comment to the OP and others, _Sage_ is an incredibly powerful _suite_ of mathematical software; on the flip side, because it is [so powerful](http://www.sagemath.org/links-components.html), answers pointing to the use of Sage can really benefit from a brief description of what components to use and how to use them.)

Answer (score 4):

You may find [this link](http://www.math.uri.edu/~pakula/462web/Websites%20related%20to%20Visual%20Complex%20Analysis.htm) helpful.  You might also enjoy [this book](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//)'s approach to complex variable.